# UiTableView in viewController - delegate and dataSource methods not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, uipageviewcontroller

I just finished a [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) about creating a UIPageViewController. The source code of the tutorial is also available in the link at the end of the article. Now instead of the imageView I wanted to add a tableView with custom cells for every page. In the PageContentViewController.h file I added the IBOutlet for the tableView which is called "theTableView".

Now for the viewController I did the following:

**viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PageContentViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageTitles;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tableViews;


@end
```

**viewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //some code
    UITableView* v1=[[UITableView alloc] init];
    v1.dataSource=self;
    v1.delegate=self;

    UITableView* v2=[[UITableView alloc] init];
    v2.dataSource=self;
    v2.delegate=self;

    _tableViews= @[v1, v2];

    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];


 // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    pageContentViewController.theTableView=self.tableViews[0];
    pageContentViewController.thetableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

 // some code
}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    //some code

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.theTableView = self.tableViews[index];

    return pageContentViewController;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustumCell *cell= (CustumCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell==nil) {cell = [[CustumCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];}

    return cell;
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

The last 3 methods are not getting called. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:added the suggestions in the answers below. Still get the same result. When I add SnowMax's solution (e.g. [self.view addSubview v1]) the methods are getting called, but the tableView does not show in the pageContentViewController because I add the subviews in the viewController. Trying to add the subviews v1 and v2 to the pageContentViewController.view results in not calling the delegate methods again?

**EDIT2**
I ended up putting the tableView outlet in the pageContentViewController.h file and set the dataSource and the delegate of the tableView there. Now it works great. Still don't know how I could've set the tableView in the viewController and correctly show the tables as pages in the pageContentViewController, but this solution will do for now. I just started learning objectiveC/cocoa so I will figure it out later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that the TableViews are not added to your view. You just initialize the view.

In the tutorial a storyboard is used to place the UI elements. You can go this way and add an UITableView to the storyboard and create a delegate and set the delegate and the datasource in the viewDidLoad method.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Set Delegate and Datasource
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
}
```

If you want to create the TableView in code you should add it to your view.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Init
    UITableView* v1=[[UITableView alloc] init];
    v1.dataSource=self;
    v1.delegate=self;

    // Place at your view
    [self.view addSubview:v1];
}
```

Comment: I added the tableViews to self.view but still got the same problem?

Comment: I want to show the tableViews in the pageContentViewController where I set the tableView outlet using the storyboard, i.e. each page should be a different tableView.

Comment: So you can see an empty tableview? Should each page have a different tableView or only different content?

Comment: I see an empty tableView for eacht page. Each page should have a different content.

Comment: And you created an Outlet, like in my answer? Can you please debug, of the Outlet is NULL inside the viewDidLoad method? If not please make sure, that the darasource and delegate is set, like in my first suggestion.

Comment: This is the problem. Is the outlet connected to the xib or storyboard? Next to the outlet (HeaderFile) is a dot, which is gray inside, of it is connected.

Comment: I added a tableView in the viewController Scene and connected it, and the methods are getting called but the app still shows the empty tableViews.

Comment: This was the first step. The only code you added for creating the cells are the three lines in cellForRowAtIndex? In this lines you did not add data there.

Comment: I added some strings in the textLabel of the cell. I'm just wondering if I could add the tableVIew in the pageContentViewController Scene instead of the viewController scene like I was trying before? Anyway I will try to figure this one out first.

Comment: I ended up putting the tableView outlet in the pageContentViewController.h file and set the dataSource and the delegate of the tableView there. Now it works great. Still don't know how I could've set the tableView in the viewController and correctly show them in the pageContentViewController, but this solution will do. Thank you very much for helping me out here! I accepted your answer because I used a similar necessary implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `tableview` and `pageViewController` to the `viewController` and set their delegates. in your code, you did not setup the pageViewController

in `viewDidLoad`, add the following :

```
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

self.pageController.dataSource = self;
[[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

PageContentViewController *initialViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
pageContentViewController.theTableView = self.tableViews[0];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

See [here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/) for a complete tutorial

Comment: I did add the pageViewController to the viewController, I just didn't include that in my code example. I used the code of the tutorial. Now I tried adding the tableView to the viewController (pageContentViewController.theTableView = self.tableViews[0];) but this still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you did every thing right but, you didn't set the `frame` of table view. Set the frame of tableview.

if you don't set the frame of `tableview` then only method getting called is .

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

hope it works for you .

Comment: I tried setting the frame in viewDidLoad (pageContentViewController.theTableView.frame=CGRectMake(...); but still got no results.